# Does TLP automatically start when my system boots?

Tags: 13.04, power-management, startup-applications

Does TLP automatically start when my system boots? Everytime i boot into Ubuntu i open a terminal and type `sudo tlp start`only then i can find the difference in the system temperature. If TLP doesnt start automatically, Is there a way to  add it as a startup applications? 
and everytime the power mode changes from ac to battery or vice versa i need to again type

`sudo tlp start`. Is there a way TLP can switch modes automatically?

As mentioned in [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TLP) link i did type  `systemctl enable tlp` but i get an error :
`systemctl: command not found`. So what do i do now?

Comment: Tlp will start automatically on Ubuntu, you dont need to do anything, please read my full answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: @Qasim Yeah i had installed following your answer. So i dont have to keep starting it everytime i boot?

Comment: no , you dont have to , check section 0 

    0.) General

TLP_ENABLE=1
 ..it will start automatically.

Answer (score 21):

> Yes TLP will automatically start you do not need to run any command

please check

```
  0.) General

  TLP_ENABLE=1
```

Set to 0 to disable TLP (Reboot needed), It should be enabled so leave the default value

[Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681)

If you're not sure you can always check whether TLP is running by typing in a terminal:

```
sudo tlp-stat -s
```

Answer (score 0):

TLP is exepcted to start automatically on every boot once you run the command :

**sudo tlp-start**

However that might not work everytime. So you should instead try running :

**sudo tlp-stat -s**

if you get the following output :
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZjKq.png)

then try running:

**systemctl enable tlp.service**

this should work for you.